# Why 'this' can be used as the argument here in Java?

Tags: java, android

```
public class Activity01 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ViewFactory {
        ...
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            LinearLayout main_view = new LinearLayout(this);
            m_Switcher = new ImageSwitcher(this);
            main_view.addView(m_Switcher);
            m_Switcher.setId(SWITCHER_ID);
            m_Switcher.setFactory(this);
            m_Switcher.setOnClickListener(this);
            setContentView(main_view);
            ...
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Above code is from an Android project, and below function's argument is set as 'this', why?

```
m_Switcher.setOnClickListener(this);
```

According to the javadoc, here should be like below:

```
public void setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener l)
```

That means the argument should be this kind: `View.OnClickListener`

So why 'this' can be there? Thanks!

Note: According to the answers, I gave a more complete code above.

Comment: Does the class implement `OnClickListener`? If so, there is your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the class declaration you will find it either `extends` or `implements` `OnClickListener`. That means that the class can be used as an `OnClickListener` (because it is one, amongst other things). That is why you can use **this** here.

Comment: So you are so familiar with this kind of code. Yes, you are complete right. This is the best answer.

Comment: Also need to say, when `m_Switcher` will be clicked `Activity01.onClick(View v)` will be called with `v` set to `m_Switcher`.